# Seeking an elegant, CSS-only method for hiding/showing auto-height content (with transitions)

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'd like a method that uses only CSS transitions, to effectively (and attractively) hide/show content on hover.

The caveat being that I wish to keep dynamic (auto) height.

It seems that the optimal route would be to transition between a `fixed height:0`, to a `height:auto`, but alas this is not yet supported by transitions in browsers.

**A clarification in response to the comments** :: This isn't so much a question of waiting until all living browsers are CSS3 compatible, but rather addressing a perceived shortcoming of CSS3 itself (eg. the lack of `height:0` > `height:auto`)

I've explored a few other ways, which can be viewed at the following fiddle (and elaborated below), but none of them satisfy me, and I'd love feedback/tips for other approaches.

http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/PWbXp/1/

**Base CSS**

```
.content{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;  
    -moz-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

**Variation #1 - The Max-Height Hack**

```
.content { max-height:0px; }
.activator:hover +.content{ max-height:2000px; }
```

*Cons*

**a.** You'll need to arbitrarily set an upper *max-height*, which, with extensive dynamic content, could potentially cut off information.

**b.** If, as a precaution to (**a**), you resort to setting a **very** high upper *max-height*, the delay on animation becomes awkward, and untenable, as the browser invisibly transitions the entire distance. Also makes easing less visually effective.

---

**Variation #2 - Padding and the Illusion of Growth**

```
.content { padding:0px; height:0px; opacity:0; }
.activator:hover +.content { padding:10px 0px; height:auto; opacity:1; }
```

*Cons*

**a.** It's jarring. It's definitely slightly better than just popping the content out of nowhere, and the effect is further sold by transitioning the opacity, but overall it's not that visually slick.

---

**Variation #3 - The Faulty Width-Only Approach**

```
.content { width:0%; }
.activator:hover +.content{ width:100%; }
```

*Cons*

**a.** As the width shrinks, the line-wrap forces any extra text onto subsequent lines, and we end up with a super tall invisible div that still demands the real-estate.

---

**Variation #4 - The Effective, but Jittery, Font-Size**

```
.content {  font-size:0em; opacity:0; }
.activator:hover +.content{  font-size:1em; opacity:1; }
```

*Cons*

**a.** While this has a nice, sweeping sort of effect, the shifting of the line-wrap as the font grows causes unappealing jitter.

**b.** This only works for content consisting of text. Other transitions would need to be added to manage the scaling of inputs, and images, and while entirely viable, this would erode the simplicity.

---

**Variation #5 - The Butteriness of Line-Height**

```
.content { line-height:0em; opacity:0; }
.activator:hover +.content{ line-height:1.2em; opacity:1; }
```

*Cons*

**a.** My favorite aesthetically, but as with #4, this works most simply with text-only content.

---

**Variation #6 - The Anti-Margin (as offered by @graphicdivine)**

```
.wrapper_6 { min-height: 20px }
.wrapper_6 .activator {z-index:10; position: relative}
.wrapper_6 .content { margin-top: -100%; }
.wrapper_6 .activator:hover +.content{ margin-top: 0 }
```

*Cons*

**a.** There is a delay on hover which is not optimal. This is the result of the `.content` being tucked invisibly quite far up the screen, and taking time to animate downwards before appearing.

**b.** The `margin-top: -100%` is relative to the containing element's width. So, with fluid designs there's the potential that when the window is shrunk quite small, the `margin-top` wont be sufficient to keep the `.content` hidden.

---

As I said before, if only we could transition between `height:0` and `height:auto`, this would all be moot.

Until then, any suggestions?

Thanks!
Leif

Comment: What is the con of using JS in this situation?

Comment: Hah! To quote that proverbial mountain-climber, _"because it's there"_.

-- I guess, it just feels that it should be elegantly doable, and a desire for the simplicity of that.

Comment: Using javascript you probably avoid some cross-browser and backwards compatibility issues. As a lot of webpages nowadays use jQuery I don't think it will harm to use it. I guess it's best to wait until more people use browser that support css3 :). Concerning suggestions, seems like I don't really have an addition to your post.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should :)

Comment: Philosophically, I feel the CSS transitions are really designed for device-centric performance. As such, I find them useful in handling the heavy lifting (The actual animation) but JS should still be used for the basics (calculating heights and initiating the CSS transitions and such).

Comment: @DA. I think I agree with the sentiment, except for the thought that JS should handle height calculations. The browser already handles this natively (height : auto) and it seems such an awkward oversight that using CSS transitions for this purpose means discarding that native ease.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, **The anti-margin**:

```
.wrapper_6 { min-height: 20px }
.wrapper_6 .activator {z-index:10; position: relative}
.wrapper_6 .content { margin-top: -100%; }
.wrapper_6 .activator:hover +.content{ margin-top: 0 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PWbXp/

Comment: Oh! I like it. My only qualm being that there is a slight delay on rollover due to the time it takes for the content to appear from beneath the 'activator'; doesn't play well with ease-in. Otherwise, very good.

Comment: After some testing, realizing now that the delay is actually because the `.content` is hidden very far up the page. The `margin:-100%` is actually too arbitrary, as it is in relation to the width of the containing element (not to its own height). This would be (is) especially problematic with fluid designs, as the width of the container can shrink low enough to push the 'anti-margin'd `.content` into visible areas. Illustrated here : http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/PWbXp/1/ (Try shrinking your window width, and you can see the 'anti-margin' example fail). Drat. Thanks though!

Comment: I think some playing with the box-sizing rules should fix some of those problems...?

Answer (score 4):

Well... I know it's been awhile, but I needed to use a height animation, and believe that a lot of other programmers still need or/and will need to do it.

So, I fell here because I needed to show mode details of a product description inside a cell-table when user hovers the cell. Without user hovering, only the maximum of 2 lines of description are shown. Once user hovers it, all lines (text can be since 1 to 8 lines, dynamic and unpredictable length) must be show with some kind of height animation.

I come to the same dilemma, and choose to use the max-height transition (setting a high max-height, which I was sure that will not cut my text), because this approach appears to me to be the cleanest solution to animate the height.

But I couldn't be satisfied with the delay on the "slide up" animation, just like You.
That's when I found a commentary about transition curve here: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animating_height/ .

The Idea of this guy is brilliant, but just this solution alone "cut-off" the effect of "slide down" animation. So thinking a little I just come to a final solution.

**So here is my solution using the Rhys's Idea** (Guy of link above):

Slide Down Animation (Hover), with a "**smooth grow**", and Slide Up Animation **without** (virtually) "**delay**":

```css
div {
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1.05, 0, 1);
  -moz-transition: max-height 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1.05, 0, 1);
  transition: max-height 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1.05, 0, 1);
  max-height: 38px;
}
div:hover {
  -webkit-transition: max-height 2s ease;
  -moz-transition: max-height 2s ease;
  transition: max-height 2s ease;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ac lorem ante. Vestibulum quis magna pretium, lacinia arcu at, condimentum odio. Ut ultrices tempor metus, sit amet tristique nibh vestibulum in. Pellentesque vel velit eget purus mollis
  placerat sed sit amet enim. Sed efficitur orci sapien, ac laoreet erat fringilla sodales.
</div>
```

Here is a Simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rnc9bbm/)

And Here is your [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWbXp/15/) updated (slice of it, indeed)

This is a perfect (in my opinion) solution for menu, descriptions and everything that isn't extremely unpredictable, but as You pointed before, there is the need to set up a high max-height, and may cut-off a surprisingly tall dynamic content. In this specific situation, I'll use jQuery/JavaScript to animate the height instead. Since the update of the content will be done using some sort of JavaScript already, I can't see any harm using a Js approach to animation.

Hope I helped somebody out there!

Comment: This is pretty neat! I put your snippet into a runnable Stack Snippet; no need to rely on just the fiddle link for the demo :)

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam! And thanks for the Stack Snippet, I didn't know this StackOverflow's feature... That's what I love here, You learn something new in your own answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use scaleY.

HTML:

```
<p>Here (scaleY(1))</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    background-color: #eee;
    transform: scaleY(0);    
    transform-origin: top;
    transition: transform 0.26s ease;
}

p:hover ~ ul {
    transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

I've made a vendor prefixed version of the above code on jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/dotnetCarpenter/PhyQc/9/

Comment: The problem with this method is that the space that the element is supposed to occupy when it's at full height is still taken up. So you can't use this if you're building say, a collapsible menu.