# CSS transtitions: Shrink height of div whose height is determined by its content

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Upon "Hide", I want to shrink (reduce height to 0px) on some divs whose height is otherwise determined by the height of their content.

This code sort of works, but the transitions only work on padding and border, not on height, which is the bulk of the vertical size, so the result isn't smooth.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yty6f45BisqpCpWzgyan)

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="msg" ng-hide="showIt">
    <div class="icon"><img src="img1.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="text">Some text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="msg" ng-hide="showIt">
    <div class="icon"><img src="img2.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="text">Some text 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.cont {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

.msg {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
/*  height:50px; THIS MAKES IT WORK, BUT I DON'T WANT TO FIX HEIGHT */
}

.msg img {  
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.msg .text {
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

.msg.ng-hide-add {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
}

.msg.ng-hide {
  height: 0; /* TRANSITION TO 0 ISN'T SMOOTH UNLESS INITIAL HEIGHT OF .msg IS SPECIFIED */
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

I'm using AngularJS ngAnimate, but that's not relevant to the question. Angular simply adds the ng-hide classes when necessary.

Further requirements:

- Pure CSS solution if possible
- No fixed height as in the `.msg` commented out section.  While this works, it means that I can't have height set dynamically by the content
- No dynamically generated height style (eg by using jQuery to calculate and explicitly set the height style on each `.msg`)
- No setting transitions styles on EVERY content element (eg `.msg.ng-hide img { height: 0; }`). I can get this working, but the contents of each `.msg` is dynamic, so each time I introduce more/different child elements I have to add transition styles to each one. Much uglier than just shrinking the parent.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to animate / transition to/from an `auto` height. That's not possible with CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seeking an elegant, CSS-only method for hiding/showing auto-height content (with transitions)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572979/seeking-an-elegant-css-only-method-for-hiding-showing-auto-height-content-with)

Comment: @Paulie_D You're the man.  I searched and searched for something like that. Thanks for pointing me to it.  Beautiful question.

Comment: So essentially, in my example, I was already using Variation #2 from the "Seeking an elegant..." link @Paulie_D shared, and had already ruled out Variations #4 and #5. Variation #3 isn't really an option, and couldn't get #6 working. #1 was the closest, but doesn't work nicely when padding etc also has to be animated. So my conclusions. This is a big hole in CSS3, and... Long live jQuery http://plnkr.co/edit/qsHhw1rzD2xS3UJnU7XY

Answer (score 3):

there is a trick for it. Instead of using `height` property. You can achive by using `max-height`

```
.msg {
    max-height: 1000px; /* depend on the largest possible */
    ...
}

.msg.ng-hide {
    max-height: 0;
    ....
}
```